# add key-value pairs in objects with spread operator

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, use-state

I have a object named `json`

```js
let json ={
    c: {
        a1:1,
        b1:{
            a2:6
        }
    }
}
```

there is a key name `b1` whose value is an Object. In that object I want to add a new key value pair `b2 : 100`.

so the `newObj` that I want to add

```js
let newObj={
    c: {
        b1:{
            b2:100 // new key-value entry
        }
    }
}
```

SO that after using spread operator I can modify the  `json` as follows

```js
json ={
    c: {
        a1:1,
        b1:{
            a2:6,
            b2:100
        }
    }
}
```

The code that I used is as follows:

```js
var json = {...json, ...newObj}
```

I know this is completely wrong as this gave an undesirable output which is as follows

```js
json={
    c: {
        b1:{
            b2:100
        }
    }
}
```

I am actually doing a React state update with `useState` hook where `json` is a state and `setJson` will set the `json`'s new state
I did it like:

```js
setJson(current => ({
  form : {
    ...current.form,
    ...newObj },
  },
}));

where newObj is an object
newObj = {
  form:{
    a:1,
    b:{
      b1:{
        b2:100, //new key-value pair to be added in b1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Please suggest an easy way to update the `json` state that can be used in that `useState` hook

**What I want**
I want to merge arbitrary objects to `json`(merge arbitrary objects (having arbitrary nesting).
The nesting could be very deep

Comment: Do you need a code that works for exactly this particular object, or that can merge arbitrary objects (with arbitrary nesting)?

Comment: I want to merge arbitrary objects to `json`.

The nesting could be very deep

Comment: Then you cannot use spread syntax (alone) for that.